# How to use Redis as back end for mosquitto ACL (JPmens plugin is used)?

Tags: authentication, redis, acl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am working on Mosquitto and plan to use Redis as the back end to handle both username/password pair authentication and ACL. I am using [JPmens' authentication plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) to do this. The authentication works well, but I can't make the ACL work. Redis uses unique keys and the usernames (keys in my cases) are used in username/password pairs for authentication purposes. I have tried to mix user name,password and topics together in sets/list, but none of them work.

the mosquitto conf:

```
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_backends redis
auth_opt_redis_host 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_redis_port 6379
auth_opt_redis_userquery GET %s
auth_opt_redis_aclquery GET %s-%s
```

Following name/password pairs are working fine for the authentication

> SET user1 PBKDF2$sha256$901$Qh18ysY4wstXoHhk$g8d2aDzbz3rYztvJiO3dsV698jzECxSg
>
> SET user2 PBKDF2$sha256$901$R74X2ae3MufMS20M$CAbXZFDmXJN7Cc28Dm/Z97OfM8Tz1JHn
>   ...

Following settings won't work for the ACL: (a/b... as topics)

> sadd user22 PBKDF2$sha256$901$Qh18ysY4wstXoHhk$g8d2aDzbz3rYztvJiO3dsV698jzECxSg a/b c/d
>
> rpush user33 PBKDF2$sha256$901$q5/N74O6Iaf/e8Cg$dEA3tZSi/sJeXKAkX39Gd3agy2WY96gE e/f

What's the correct way to do so?
In the Redis API, `aclrequery` shows that:

```
Single stepping until exit from function be_redis_aclcheck, which has no line number information.

redisCommand (c=0x6537d0, format=0x6561c0 "GET user1-t/c") at hiredis.c:1345
1345    void *redisCommand(redisContext *c, const char *format, ...) {
(gdb) bt
0  redisCommand (c=0x6537d0, format=0x6561c0 "GET my-t/c") at hiredis.c:1345
1  0x00007ffff5e61376 in be_redis_aclcheck () from /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
2  0x00007ffff5e5c351 in mosquitto_auth_acl_check ()
```

from /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so

Here, `user1` is the user name and `t/c` is the topic. `GET user1-t/c` seems to tell me a string type is expected in the Redis database. Can anyone give me an example of how to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how it works. If MQTT broker only allow client user1 to pub and sub "a/b" and "c/d" topics, the correct ACL data in Redis for the JPmens plugin will be:

user1-a/b 2

user1-c/d 2

"user1-a/c" is the key and 2 is the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not preferred, if Redis goes down for any reason your entire system will be down also.

It will be a SPF (single point of failure) in your architecture.